# Select distinct rows where all values are in group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have a table that stores a one to many relationsion (`caseid` to `code`). It is possible for one `caseid` to have many `code`s.

I would like to select all rows where all the `code`s for a given `caseid` are contained within a group of `codes`. If a `caseid` is associated with any `code` that *is not* in this group, then exclude it, regardless of if all the other `codes` are in the group.

I would then like to build a table where each unique `caseid` has a single row and four Boolean columns (one for each code I am looking for) denoting if that code is present.

Here is my query so far:

```
select distinct(caseid), _43280, _43279, _43282, _43281 from
(select caseid,   
  0 < countif(code = "43280") as _43280,
  0 < countif(code = "43279") as _43279,
  0 < countif(code = "43282") as _43282,
  0 < countif(code = "43281") as _43281
from mytable
inner join (
  select caseid, logical_and(code in ('43280', '43279', '43282', '43281')) as include,
  from mytable
  group by caseid
  having include
  ) 
using(caseid)
group by caseid
order by caseid)
```

An example table may be:

```
caseid | code
1         43280
1         43279
1         43282
2         43280
2         43279
2         43282
2         99999
3         43280
3         43279
3         43282
```

It should come out as:

```
caseid | _43280 | _43279 | _43282 | _43281
 1        TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
 3        TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select caseid,
    logical_or(code = 43280) code_43280,
    logical_or(code = 43279) code_43279,
    logical_or(code = 43282) code_43282,
    logical_or(code = 43281) code_43281
from mytable
group by caseid
having not logical_or(code not in (43280, 43279, 43282, 43281))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and using BQ Scripting

```
#standardsql
create temp table data as
select caseid, array_agg(code) as codes, 
from `project.dataset.table` t
left join unnest(['43280', '43279', '43282', '43281']) test_code
on code = test_code 
group by caseid
having countif(test_code is null) = 0;

execute immediate (
  select """
  select caseid, """ || 
    string_agg("""max(if(code = '""" || code || """', true, false)) as _""" || replace(code, '.', '_'), ', ') 
  || """
  from data, unnest(codes) code 
  group by caseid
  """
  from unnest(['43280', '43279', '43282', '43281']) code
);
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]